# How to use Wordpress spelling checker plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

The wordpress spelling checker plugin (version 3.5.1) shows this error:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content/wp-config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\spell-plugin\spellInclude.php on line 7
```

Comment: It means that plugin is not yet installed properly.

Comment: `wp-config.php` usually belongs in the wordpress directory, not `wp-content`

Comment: how to use i have gooing to this path http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/spell-plugin.php error show:The requested URL /wordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/spell-plugin.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have this file in:

```
C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content/wp-config.php
```

If yes, my guess is to change from

```
require_once(C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content/wp-config.php)
```

to (not all systems accept both slashes)

```
require_once(C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\wp-config.php)
```

Comment: :how to use i have gooing to this path http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/spell-plugin.php error show:The requested URL /wordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/spell-plugin.php was not found on this server.